# Unable to post video preview for iOS app

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, app-store-connect

I am unable to submit the video preview of my app.  Length is ok and the upload is accepted followed by the message "Your file could not be loaded.  Try again"

Answer (score 1):

Video upload is broken in iTunes Connect right now, due to mixed content issues, enforced in Safari 9. Either use Safari 8, or try a different browser and choose to allow mixed content.